# Using conditional values from an array in an if...statement

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of conditions :

```
$arrConditions = array ('>=2', '==1', '<=10');
```

...which I want to be able to use in an if...statement.

IE.

```
if (5 $arrConditions[0])
{
  ...do something
}
```

...which would be the same as :

```
if (5 >= 2)
{
  ...do something
}
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `eval`, but it will be horribly slow and you didn't hear it from me. Or, much preferably, you can roll up your sleeves and do it manually: `switch($operator) { case '==': $result = $input == $operand; }` etc.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, I've done it manually but was just wondering if there was a more elegant solution...

Comment: Get some refresher on basics of programming. `IF` requires a `condition` which outputs `true` or `false`. $arrCondition[0] is just a string and there is no operation happening there. which means no evaluation and no output. you can use `switch case` for symbols but it is impossible in case of `IF`.

Comment: @Abhinav...no need to be rude! That's the whole question, as in, is it possible - which, by the way, it would be using eval().

Comment: Sorry for sounding sarcastic, I didn't really mean to complain. what you asked above is not possible unless you design your own programming language and make this possible in it. As far as i know, if statement can perform only mathematics and comparison operations and operate only on true/false output variation. Most elegant solution is use of Switch case. Not to forget you need to perform typecasing to convert string to an operater. Using Eval is horribly slow, complex, and error pron.

Comment: to be strict, "if statement" do not perform any mathematics. It does comparison only. It compares passed expression with TRUE. And then does execute (or not execute) following code block. That's all that IF statement does. While passed expression could be almost any possible PHP expression. including comparison operators and such

Comment: what about my answer ?? is that what you are looking for ???

Comment: @Abhinav...it is possible, using the eval() function, which while not recommended, does work and it pretty straight-forward. I simply build each case as a string with the array condition, then perform an eval(), IE: eval("switch(TRUE){".$strCases."}");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
<?php

$arrConditions = array('==2', '==9', '==5', '==1', '==10', '==6', '==7');

$count = 0;
$myval = 0;
foreach ($arrConditions as $cond) {
  $str = "if(5 $cond) { return  $count;}";
  $evalval = eval($str);
  if (!empty($evalval)) {
    $myval = $count;
  }
  $count++;
}

switch ($myval) {
  case 0: echo '==2 satisfied';
    break;
  case 1: echo '==9 satisfied';
    break;
  case 2: echo '==5 satisfied';
    break;
  case 3: echo '==1 satisfied';
    break;
  case 4: echo '==10 satisfied';
    break;
  default : echo 'No condition satisfied';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Such a requirement is a sure sign of a bad design.
Most likely you can do that another, more usual way.

Nevertheless, never use eval for such things.
At least store each operator in pairs - an operator and operand.

```
$arrConditions = array (
    array('>=',2),
    array('==',1),
    array('<=',10),
);
```

and then use switch:

```
list ($operator,$operand) = $arrConditions[0];
switch($operator) { 
    case '==': 
        $result = ($input == $operand); 
        break;
    case '>=': 
        $result = ($input >= $operand); 
        break;
    // and so on
}
```

But again - most likely you can solve it another, much easier way.